# wget prevent saving to disk

Tags: wget

I am trying to crawl the internet starting at a certain website and get a list of URLs that were visited. This is what I have so far:

```
wget --spider -r --no-verbose -o out.txt <url>
```

The problem with this is that it creates a folder structure on the disk of the websites it visited. I don't want to download any files or create folders on disk. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `-nd` or `--no-directories` option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but the `--delete-after` option might work for you.

Comment: `--delete-after` does not delete the directory.

Comment: @Dennis ok, good to know.